# How to use a google distant matrix api key and an google maps api key in one app?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

im programming an app for android that helps me to find the optimal parking space in my hometown.

For that I'm using Google maps API in for android. I managed to get it to work to display the car parks in the city.

Now I want to use google distant matrix API to calculate the traveltime by car between my position and the different car parks and additionally the traveltime by foot from the car parks to a user specific location in the town.

Since I have to use

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?"
       + "origins=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
       + "&destinations="     +waypoints+"&sensor=false&mode=driving&key=GOOGLE_key";
```

I need to add an API key for GOOGLE_key.

I already have an API key for the distant matrix but I'm hesitating to use that in the code, since on the tutorials they advise against that.

Now to my questions:

1. How and where can I store that key?
2. I want to use something like ... `+ "&sensor=false&mode=driving&key=" + GOOGLE_key;` without using the API key in the code.

Additional Info:

In my AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="@string/google_maps_key"
```

and in google_maps_api.xml:

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
```

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable like `GOOGLE_key`, then attach `google_maps_key` string to this via `getResources().getSring()`. Now, you can use `"&sensor=false&mode=driving&key=" + GOOGLE_key;`

Comment: i tried somehing like this `private String distance_matrix_key = getResources().getString(google_distance_matrix_key);` and it can't resolve symbol 'google_distance_matrix_key', so i added  `<string name="google_distance_matrix_key">xxxxxxxxxxxx</string>` in strings.xml. That didn't work for me. Where do I put the Key to find it with `getResources().getString()`?

Comment: Where is your google_maps_api.xml ? If is in strings, you must use `getString(R.string.google_maps_key)`

Comment: google_maps_api.xml is located at app/res/values/google_maps_api.xml. strings,xml is located at app/res/values/strings.xml.

Comment: ok, copy the `google_maps_api.xml` content to strings.xml and use `getString(R.string.google_maps_key)`

Comment: Thank you that worked. If i want to save the key in google_maps_api.xml. Is there a way to reference that through 'getString()'?

Comment: You are welcome :) I think you are not access the key in `google_maps_api.xml`. But you should enter the api key on your `google_maps_api.xml` too, for the map working clearly.